# Python - Finds the index of the smallest element in the list A from index k onwards

Tags: python, list, indexing, min

I am stuck in finding how I can take the "k" in consideration to solve the following problem. Basically, it should start at index k and look for the lowest value in the range from k until the end of the list.

```
def find_min_index(A, k):
    """
    Finds the index of the smallest element in the list A from index k onwards

    Parameters:
        A (list)
        k: index from which start search

    Example use:
    >>> find_min_index([1, 2, 5, -1], 0)
    3
    >>> find_min_index([1, 1, 1, 5, 9], 2)
    2
    """

    minpos = A.index(min(A))
    return minpos
```

Comment: What have you done so far? You need to have list[k:] and find the smallest element within a loop or something like that.

Comment: `k + numpy.argmin(A[k:])`

Comment: @Ekrem just the last two lines including minpos, than I tried somehow include the k steps but didnt suceed..

Comment: @dobera after my comment, some decent answers were already sent. As I see, you struggled with making a sublist starting with 'k'th index.

Answer (score 1):

One-liner solution is this:

```
return A[k:].index(min(A[k:]) + k
```

You select the minimal element from A[k:], find its index in A[k:] and add k to it to compensate the search area.

A slightly neater solution is this:

```
slice = A[k:]
return slice.index(min(slice)) + k
```

Comment: You probably shouldn't slice twice. Slice once, store in a variable and reuse.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `k` to the index calculated from a sliced input list:

```
def find_min_index(A, k):
    sliced = A[k:]
    return k + sliced.index(min(sliced))

find_min_index([1, 2, 5, -1], 2)    # 3
find_min_index([1, 1, 1, 5, 9], 2)  # 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to find the index of min:

```
def find_min_index(A, k):
    """
    Finds the index of the smallest element in the list A from index k onwards

    Parameters:
        A (list)
        k: index from which start search

    Example use:
    >>> find_min_index([1, 2, 5, -1], 0)
    3
    >>> find_min_index([1, 1, 1, 5, 9], 2)
    2
    """

    o, _ = min(enumerate(A[k:]), key=lambda i: i[1])
    minpos = k + o
    return minpos


print(find_min_index([1, 2, 3, 4], 1))
print(find_min_index([4, 3, 2, 1], 1))
```

**Output**

```
1
3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `enumerate` to keep track of the original index before you slice the list with `k` as the starting index:

```
from operator import itemgetter
def find_min_index(A, k):
    return min(list(enumerate(A))[k:], key=itemgetter(1))[0]
```

so that:

```
print(find_min_index([1, 2, 5, -1], 0))
print(find_min_index([1, 1, 1, 5, 9], 2))
```

would output:

```
3
2
```